# CREATE TABLE in SQL behind Power BI

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi

I am building a Power BI tool tracking patients going to rooms.  Because of the uncertainty of beds and rooms as we expand capacity, I have created a table in SQL that I bounce against server data.  It works in SQL Server but not in Power BI.  Can I create a table like this in the SQL Power BI?  Or is there another way to do this once the SQL is in Power BI?

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE  #ROOMS   ([FACILITY] VARCHAR(5), [FLOOR] VARCHAR(100), [ROOM_NAME] VARCHAR(100), 
                [ROOM_TYPE] VARCHAR(100), [ICU_ACUTE] VARCHAR(5), [NORMAL_OCC] INT, 
                [ADDITONAL_BEDS] INT, [TTL_PTS_IN_ROOM] INT)

INSERT INTO #ROOMS  SELECT  'HSP1',     '3',    'OSC',  'Surg',     'ICU',  6,  6,  12
INSERT INTO #ROOMS  SELECT  'HSP2',     '1',    'ED 01',    'EMERGENCY',    'ACUTE',    1,  0,  1
INSERT INTO #ROOMS  SELECT  'HSP2',     '1',    'ED 02',    'EMERGENCY',    'ACUTE',    1,  0,  1
INSERT INTO #ROOMS  SELECT  'HSP2',     '1',    'ED 03',    'EMERGENCY',    'ACUTE',    1,  0,  1
```

Comment: # means that it is a TEMP table.  #ROOMS is created and data inserted.  And in sqlserver SSMS you are still in the same session, and the Select * From #ROOMS works.  But I may guess that in powerbi the first session is dropped, and there goes the table, and the second session with the Select fails?

Comment: It does not seem to like to CREATE a table. This is the error:  Microsoft SQL: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CREATE'.
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Maybe try just 1 column, say [FACILITY]

Comment: You can define a table in DAX or M but I'd guess Power BI isn't going to be able to create tables in SQL since it's only designed to read DBs, not write to them (although I guess it can execute stored procedures).

Comment: Alexis, I think you are right.  All the research I have done says the same thing.  I will have to try a different approach.  Thank you!  And thank you donPablo.